# Flutter IOS app not working same as Android with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Flutter app for **IOS** and **Android**. Today I noticed a weird issue. The Android app reads data from a specified path without any issue. However the **IOS** app is not reading the data from the full path.

For example:

```
// The path I am trying to read data. (_platform could be Ios. or Android)
final _path = 'admin/APP-CONFIG/APP-DETAILS/BUILD/${_platform}';
final _ref = await getDatabaseInstance().ref().child(_path); 
var _ds = await _ref.get();  
print(_ds.value);
```

The above code reads data all the way till '**admin/APP-CONFIG/APP-DETAILS/BUILD/Android**'. However, if I run the same code with IOS, it reads till '**admin/APP-CONFIG**'

I tried changing the code by dividing the path as follow but it is still working the same way.

```
final _ref = await getDatabaseInstance()
  .ref()
  .child('admin')
  .child('APP-CONFIG')
  .child('APP-DETAILS')
  .child('BUID')
  .child(_platform);
```